# JavaMail error + Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?

Tags: jakarta-mail, pop3, zimbra

Using below code to read mails from a Zimbra mail server.

```
String SSL_FACTORY = "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory";

Properties pop3Props = new Properties();

pop3Props.setProperty("mail.pop3.socketFactory.class", SSL_FACTORY);
pop3Props.setProperty("mail.pop3.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
pop3Props.setProperty("mail.pop3.auth", "true");
pop3Props.setProperty("mail.pop3.port",  "110");
pop3Props.setProperty("mail.pop3.socketFactory.port", "110");

URLName url = new URLName("pop3", host, 110, "",username, password);

Session session = Session.getInstance(pop3Props, null);
Store store = new POP3SSLStore(session, url);
store.connect();
```

But keep getting this error

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Connect failed;
  nested exception is:
    javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
    at com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store.protocolConnect(POP3Store.java:148)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:275)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:156)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:105)
    at VerifyMail.readPOP3(VerifyMail.java:177)
    at VerifyMail.main(VerifyMail.java:20)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.handleUnknownRecord(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readLine(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.mail.pop3.Protocol.simpleCommand(Protocol.java:347)
    at com.sun.mail.pop3.Protocol.<init>(Protocol.java:91)
    at com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store.getPort(POP3Store.java:201)
    at com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store.protocolConnect(POP3Store.java:144)
    ... 5 more
```

Can anyone help on how to resolve this?

Comment: Tried with this code 

Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.pop3.auth",true);
props.put("mail.pop3.starttls.enable", true);
Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
session.setDebug(true);
Store store= session.getStore("pop3");
store.connect(host,username,password);
Folder folder = store.getFolder("INBOX");

ERROR---

javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: only valid after entering TLS mode at com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store.protocolConnect(POP3Store.java:146)
 at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:275)

i would appreciate if someone can help on this code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read this [list of common mistakes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes) and then clean up your code.

The [Gmail example](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#gmail) should work for you as well, although obviously you'll need to change the host name.

Comment: Bill, still getting same error--- javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: only valid after entering TLS mode   CODE--Properties props=System.getProperties();Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);session.setDebug(true);Store store= session.getStore("pop3");store.connect(host,110,username,password);

Comment: Added(props.put("mail.pop3.starttls.enable", true);) and tested with latest JavaMail API and now getting this error javax.mail.MessagingException:Connect failed;nested exception is:
java.io.IOException: Could not convert socket to TLS at com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store.protocolConnect(POP3Store.java:210)
Caused by:java.io.IOException: Could not convert socket to TLS
Caused by:javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Answer (score 0):

This will help you bypass certificate process and get directly to ssl host

```
    MailSSLSocketFactory sf = null;
    try
    {
        sf = new MailSSLSocketFactory();
    }
    catch (GeneralSecurityException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
            sf.setTrustAllHosts(true);

    Properties pop3Props = new Properties();
    pop3Props.setProperty("mail.pop3.ssl.enable", "true");
    pop3Props.setProperty("mail.protocol.ssl.trust", "pop3.live.com");
    pop3Props.put("mail.pop3s.ssl.socketFactory", sf);
    pop3Props.setProperty("mail.pop3s.port", "995");

    Session session = Session.getInstance(pop3Props);

    try
    {
    /* Get a Store object*/
       Store store = session.getStore("pop3s");
    //process further activity 
    }
```