# Read Inbox using Java

Tags: jakarta-mail

I am working in a company as an intern and everyone in the company uses outlook for mails.
I couldn't figure out a way to read emails from the Inbox.

Let me give a view about my project. I am using JavaMail API for mails.

My first task - To send mails from java program using Reminder system, which I have successfully completed, by using the host, protocol, username and no password. There is no need of entering password, because if i try to enter the password it stopped working. Its working only without password.

so basically, I can send email using other employees in the company using there email address as "From" because there is no password need to be entered, possible only from java program.

My second task - To read the subject of the mail and the sender details and do some task...

There is no password to enter, but

```
Store store = session.getStore("smtp"); 
//I tried with imap, pop3, but everything gives error "No Such Provided"


store.connect("email@domain.co.uk", "PASSWORD");
```

store.connect() doesn't allow me to use the method without password.

The software will be using a new email address which is not the same address in users outlook but for testing I am using my email address first, because the software is going to be used by different users/computers.

If i try this way

```
session.getStore("imaps");
store.connect("host","username","password");


Error:
DEBUG: getProvider() returning 
javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc]

DEBUG: mail.imap.fetchsize: 16384
DEBUG: mail.imap.statuscachetimeout: 1000
DEBUG: mail.imap.appendbuffersize: -1
 DEBUG: mail.imap.minidletime: 10

DEBUG: trying to connect to host "host", port 993, isSSL true

javax.mail.MessagingException: Connection refused: connect;
 nested exception is:


java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:618)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:291)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:172)

at TestMail.InboxReader.main(InboxReader.java:52)
    Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:351)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:213)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:200)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:570)
at 
    com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:141)
at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:284)
at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:227)
at com.sun.mail.iap.Protocol.<init>(Protocol.java:109)
at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPProtocol.<init>(IMAPProtocol.java:104)
at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:585)
... 3 more
   Java Result: 2
```

Comment: One more thing, I am using Netbeans SE with JavaMail API, is it something I have to use Netbeans EE or some apache servers. Because I don't have advance knowledge on JavaMail.

Comment: What is your company's mail server? Is it MS Exchange Server?

Comment: Yes it is MS Exchange server!

Answer (score 1):

Use Exchange Web Services (EWS) API for seamless integration with Exchange Server. Quoting from MS site

> EWS provides access to much of the same data that is made available through Microsoft Office Outlook.

EWS basics - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/dd877045(v=exchg.140).aspx
EWS Java API - http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/ewsjavaapi

Answer (score 0):

Need more details...

See the [JavaMail FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html) and post the [debug output](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) when it fails.  Also, the exact code you're using might be helpful.

You can test it all using code that comes with JavaMail, so you can determine whether the problem is in your code or something else.  See the msgshow.java demo program included in the JavaMail download bundle.

Comment: if I use the code provided in this website, by providing the host, port, username-my email address, password-as i use to login into the system   http://www.javaplex.com/blog/using-javamail-api-read-emails-from-gmail/ I will this error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12366765/javamail-error-unrecognized-ssl-message-plaintext-connection

Comment: @debug output - when i use command prompt and type the telnet host port, i received message saying 220 Unauthorized use prohibited. Does it mean i have no access?

Comment: That's what it sounds like.  Do you get that message as soon as you connect, before you type anything?  What port are you connecting to?  Perhaps your server wants you to connect on the SSL port?

Comment: I get that message as soon as connect and if i dont do anything, after sm times i will recieve another message as connection disconnected.i use port 25 to connect, but how to connect to the ssl port?

Comment: Port 25 is the plain text SMTP port.  If you're trying to connect to your IMAP server, you need to use the correct IMAP port.  It's getting confusing as to what you're actually trying to accomplish.  Maybe you should update your question with your latest code and the debug output?

Comment: sorry for the delay response, i updated my question with the code and error.

Comment: Looks like your Exchange server is not configured to accept IMAP connections over SSL.  You can try "imap" instead of "imaps", but perhaps the server is not configured for IMAP at all.  Talk to your server administrator.  Also, the [JavaMail FAQ has tips for debugging connection problems](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#condebug), to determine whether it's a networking/server problem, or a JavaMail/application problem.